# Why does concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor execute synchronously?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this simple script:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

executor= concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)

def pow():
    time.sleep(1)
    return 5


def main():
    future = executor.submit(pow)
    print(future.result())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

it will print `5`

my question is - I would think the `pow` job would execute asynchronously - why I am able to print the `future.result()` value seemingly synchronously?

Comment: `pow()` is executed asynchronously, it's you who decide to wait for it to finish when you call for `future.result()` (which is _synchronizing_ it)... From the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result) : _Return the value returned by the call. If the call hasn’t yet completed then this method will wait up to timeout seconds._

Comment: ok thanks, I am looking to create a while loop (reading from a socket) for an infinite amount of time in a worker thread. how can I do that? you mentioned it will wait up to "timeout" seconds, but if I want it to run forever in that separate thread?

Comment: Then just don't attempt to fetch the result from your main thread (or any other thread) as it will _pause_ it, deal with the data/printing/whatever within the thread itself (i.e. `print(5)` in your `pow()` function above instead of waiting for its result in your main thread).

Comment: yep that's right thanks...I wonder if there is a way to put a job onto the threadpool without returning a future, since I don't need a return value in my case

Comment: Whenever you _submit_ a job to a `ThreadPoolExecutor` it will return a futures object - you don't have to store it or reference it in any way if you don't want to, tho.